# Check if the values of one array are in another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if array number 2 contains all of the values in array number 1. I am not aware of any method that does this so I developed one that works, I think. Is there a better way to do this, is this a good solution?

```
    var contains = function(a1, a2){
var cCount = 0;
for (var i=0; i<a1.length; i++){
     for (var j=0; j<a2.length; j++){
         if (a1[i] == a2[j]){
             cCount++;             
         }}}
if (cCount == a1.length){
    return true;
}

  };
```

Comment: would it contain it in the same order or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: No the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, there is a solution... I'll post it below

Comment: What if array1 is `Array(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)` and array2 is `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`? Should this return true or false.

Comment: That would be true. The item in array 2 are all in array1. I did this for a tic-tac-toe game. Array 1 is win condition and array2 represents the palyers xs or os. Therefor as long as they satisfy the win condition, in any order, I want to return true. Additionally, there will be no duplicate values either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a bit simplified code:

```
function contains(array1, array2){
    var found = false;
    for (i in array1) {
       for (j in array2) {
           if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
              found = true;
           }
       }
       if (!found) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

another solution I don't really like it but it's shorter...

```
function contains (arr1, arr2) {
   var specialChar = "|"; // Use any char or a sequence that won't exist in values.
   var str = specialChar + arr2.join(specialChar) + specialChar;
   for (i in arr1) if (str.indexOf(specialChar + arr1[i] + specialChar) == -1) return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then no other solution is possible

Comment: No other solution? This is such a basic concept, i'm surprised there isn't a jQuery method already.

Answer (score 1):

You could check sizes before starting. return false when one is not present instead using a counter. and return true if it reach the end. And use indexof instead looping through a2 every time.

```
var contains = function(a1, a2){
    if (a1.length>a2.length) return false;
    for (var i=0; i<a1.length; i++){
        if (a2.indexOf(a1[i])<0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you messed up your brackets on the second if

Comment: your solution is written better than mine (the one marked correct below), I didn't know that indexOf works directly with arrays without converting them to strings

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is O(n * n) i.e. order n-squared.

You could sort the arrays first and then sequentially check the elements in the sorted arrays for a match. This will give you an O(n log n) solution. Also you can short circuit the check by ensuring that the size of array2 <= the size of array1.

Evidently this only matters if your arrays are sufficiently big.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in O(n) if you have a 3rd object that you use to keep track of the items that have been seen already. This assumes that the lookup in `seen` is O(1) (which presumably it is - [What's the big O for JavaScript's array when used as a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858411/whats-the-big-o-for-javascripts-array-when-used-as-a-hash))

```
var seen = {};
arr2.forEach(function(el) {
  seen[el] = true;
});

var allContained = true;
arr1.forEach(function(el) {
  if ( allContained && !seen[el] ) {    
    allContained = false;
  }
});

return allContained;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use the `Array.every()` method (though this is, of course, dependent upon a browser that implements this method) in conjunction with `Array.indexOf()`, which would result in something akin to the following:

```
var contains = function(needle, haystack){
    return needle.every(function(a){
        return haystack.indexOf(a) > -1;
    });
};
```

Combining that with the approach you've already produced (testing for browser-support):

```
var contains = function(needle, haystack){
    if ([].every){
        return needle.every(function(a){
            return haystack.indexOf(a) > -1;
        });
    }
    else {
        var result = true;
        for (var i = 0, len = needle.length; i < len; i++){
            if (haystack.indexOf(needle[i]) === -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
var a1 = [1,2,3],
    a2 = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(contains(a1, a2));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yD3Eh/).

Note that the `else` code isn't optimised, it's simply there to demonstrate the code. Having said that, there is a shim for `Array.every()` at the MDN page (in the references, below) that might make things easier.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).