# Javascript: Most Efficient Way To Use 2 Dimensional Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am currently making a tile map for a platformer.

I know in other languages, when you refer to a 2 dimensional array, it is faster to do:

```
world[y][x]
```

But, in javascript, does it matter? Can you do:

```
world[x][y]
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That looks fine to me. Your question implies there's an alternative way to access multidimensional array elements. I'm not sure there is another way

Comment: @henrywright OPs question is about data locality, check the order of indexes.

Comment: @zerkms Right, I see now.

Answer (score 2):

First off, [Arrays in *JavaScript* are just specialized objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So when you have `var a = ["entry"]` and then go `a[0]`, you are accessing a property of `a` stored as `"0"`. Since all properties are converted to strings for *JavaScript* this means `a[0] === a["0"]`. Unlike in languages such as *C++* when creating a double array you have to go `darray[y][x]` because of how the memory is created, with *JavaScript* we can assign an object to that location (since it is just another property) such that we can interpret how we want to!

```
var world = [], // Start out with something empty.
    X = Y = 10; // Get dims.
// Fill that sucker up!
for(var i = 0; i < X; ++i)
{
    var x = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < Y; ++j)
    {
        // Forces a place holder in the array.
        x[j] = undefined;
    }
    world[i] = x;
}
```

And presto! Now, you can go `world[x][y]` to get objects stored in those locations. Just as a little bit more information, the place holder is used to make the array actually have a length of `Y` as well.

---

Now, let's come back to the fact that an array is just a specialized object. This means we are accessing a property of the object `world` then again in the entry stored at that location. Therein, the [speed of access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858411/whats-the-big-o-for-javascripts-array-when-used-as-a-hash) is limited by how the properties were chosen to be stored (as @zerms pointed out in the comments).

Comment: "Therein, the property is stored in a hash map" --- it makes sense to mention, that the standard does not put any constraints here. So it might be a tree, or an array, up to engine implementors. So in general one cannot state that property access has constant time approximation for any arbitrary implementation.

Comment: `// Prevents from duplicating x everywhere.
    (function(x) { world[i] = x })(x);` --- this code makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms. It is true that ECMAScript standard places no constraints on the implementation, that is my bad. Here is some information on the [access time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858411/whats-the-big-o-for-javascripts-array-when-used-as-a-hash). Sorry, about that... I pulled that from some code I used from a terrain sim where I needed to prevent `x` from being the same object in every entry. Let me try this again, I did that from my phone lol